# "taken necessary" or "taken as necessary" or "taken to be necessary"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, collocation

A is taken…

> 1. …necessary for B
> 2. …as necessary for B
> 3. …to be necessary for B

The most and least popular ones on the web are respectively 2 and 3. On [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taken%20as%20necessary%2C%20taken%20necessary%2C%20taken%20to%20be%20necessary%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaken%20as%20necessary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaken%20necessary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaken%20to%20be%20necessary%3B%2Cc0), 1 is the most popular, even though it has recently lost its place to 2, and 3 is again the least popular.

[image]

Which one is the best? Why? Or does it really matter?

An example for #1:

> an arrangement has been made with a third party where the third party
>   has confirmed that the share has been located and measures have been
>   **taken necessary for** a reasonable expectation that settlement can be
>   effected when due. [Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=36&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0mb-Ktf_UAhWFZpoKHehbBoA4HhAWCD0wBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.proskauer.com%2Ffiles%2FNews%2F9bc8dd5a-90bd-4d1c-a171-babb209021ca%2FPresentation%2FNewsAttachment%2F4316b865-fedb-42b0-96fb-7766c75fba79%2Fprivate-investment-funds-update-february-2012.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGW6n-o9Va5rDsrJkeJReNBlHZD_A)

Comment: Refine your Google Ngram searches to _was taken necessary / was taken as necessary / was taken to be necessary_. There will be many false positives for 'has taken necessary steps' etc on your search. If this fails, repeat with Google searches. If this gives strange results, add this information to your question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Here it doesn't give anything with "was". Weird! It says: No valid ngrams to plot! Ngrams not found: was taken necessary 
The Ngram Viewer is case sensitive. Check your capitalization!

Comment: I have to agree with Edwin's earlier comment. In addition,  the Ngram displays results without the auxiliary "be" and without the preposition "for". Here's the same Ngram but with "for" included in the results https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taken+as+necessary+for%2Ctaken+necessary+for%2Ctaken+to+be+necessary+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaken%20as%20necessary%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaken%20to%20be%20necessary%20for%3B%2Cc0

Comment: And, I confess, I don't really understand what `A is taken necessary for B` is supposed to mean. Can you provide a real life example, one less abstract? Not my upvote!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I found this on the Internet: Our team assists you in every step that needs to be taken necessary for selling a home, including signings of agreements, advertising, open home inspections, ... https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=26&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj3y7u24frUAhUJB8AKHaX5CWc4FBAWCEEwBQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FLJHookerOranPark%2F&usg=AFQjCNFx5zH12G4JD3Pf3lKGzoT0_dAMNA

Comment: That last example equates to *taken [**, that is**] necessary* rather than *taken **as** necessary* (it's clumsy and redundant, so not a great example in any case). In fact, so far as I can see, none of the [Google Books results for *taken necessary*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22taken+necessary%22) equate to *taken as necessary*. Any time you see something funny in Ngram, it's a good idea to do a spot check of the actual results to make sure you're not getting spurious results somehow.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't catch your reply. You should include that example sentence in  your question. It explains perfectly why you asked the question in the first place. Just include the name of the source and a link.

Comment: @1006a What about the example I just added to the question?

Comment: That also looks like it is omitting "that are" rather than "as": *measures have been taken **that are** necessary*. That means something like "[they] have taken the necessary measures".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Would like to know your view on what is said about "consider as" here: community.languagetool.org/rule/show/… (thanks in advance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A is taken necessary for B

is just wrong. You could have

> A is necessary for B

(that is, B requires A) but "taken necessary" doesn't make sense to me.

> A taken as necessary for B

is the normal usage for medicine where there are no dosage restrictions; you take the medicine when you need it, as in

> One lozenge taken as necessary for a sore throat

but

> A is taken to be necessary for B  (or A is taken as necessary for B )

means something different - it means that A is generally regarded as a requirement for B, for example

> A screwdriver is taken to be necessary to remove a screw.

Comment: Did you omit "is" intentionally? And why "is taken necessary" is just wrong?

Comment: oops -yes, that's a typo. Thanks for spotting it :).

Comment: @Sasan 'Is taken necessary' doesn't work, just like 'is seen necessary'. 'Is considered necessary', 'is deemed necessary', and 'is felt necessary' can all be used with the 'to be' omitted. 'Is regarded necessary' doesn't sound idiomatic. English verbs don't behave in logical ways: they're idiosyncratic.

Comment: 'A is taken as necessary for B' also has the sense 'A is taken as being necessary for B'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I tried all of them with "for" just to avoid the false positives that you mentioned. There were none for "taken necessary for". It can be found in google books and other sources on the web, though. Why so?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This comment of yours raises more questions. So you say that "regarded/considered/etc.+adjective" are always wrong and should come with "as"?

Comment: I said 'can', not 'must'. I'd recommend that you look at the sister site, ELL, Sasan.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would like to know your view on what is said about "consider" here: https://community.languagetool.org/rule/show/EUPUB_CONSIDER_AS?lang=en&subId=1   (thanks in advance)

Comment: @Sasan The articles at [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/consider), [M-W Learnersdictionary.com](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/consider-and-consider-as) and [Rogermue's answer on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67721/when-to-omit-as-in-the-cases-below) are more accurate.